# Failed to pass variable from a PHP function to another at the same file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two php functions `getFeed ()` and `selectURL ()`. The `selectURL ()` function aim to get a URL as String from a javascript function:

```
function selectURL () {
if(isset($_POST['Option']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['Option'];
}
return $uid;
}
```

Result is shown at this image:
[image: Response of selectURL ()]

I want to pass this response to `getFeed()` function. In other words, I want to put this response to the `$url` variable created in `getFeed ()` function:

```
function getFeed() {
    // When I display $url
     echo $url; 
 /** I want to get as response the link shown in the image  (http://www.elkhabar.com/feeds)**/
}
```

`getFeed()` have to be executed when I click on a Button called Start:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success col-xs-3" id="start"> <i class="fa fa-play"></i>Start</button>
```

The AJAX script:

```
$('#start').click(function(){
            var $item = $('#test');
                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?function=getFeed',
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data){
                    var articles = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each (articles, function (key, value) { 
                        $item.append('<div id="item"><ul><li><h4>'+ value.title +'</h4></li> <li>'+ value.description+'</li><li><a href="'+value.link+'">Lire+</a></li></ul>');
                        console.log('success',data);

                    });

                    }
                });
            });
```

So, how I could do that?

Comment: which button? where is it? where is the js file? where is the ajax code? everything is missing here!

Comment: @AminAdel you can see the code now

Comment: @AminAdel can you help me to passe a variable in function to another

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a session variable. Ordinary variables don't persist between different scripts.

Put `session_start();` at the beginning of the script to enable sessions. Then code the functions as:

```
function selectURL() {
    if (isset($_POST['Option'])) {
        $_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['option'];
    }
}

function getFeed() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
        $url = $_SESSION['url'];
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
    echo json_encode($url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. where I do call `getFeed(selectURL())`?. Because I want to display the result using AJAX

Comment: You call it in `rssnews.inc.php`, in the code that runs when `$_GET['function'] == 'getFeed'`

Comment: I get an error: 
`<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for getFeed(), called in C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php on line 33 and defined in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: uid in <b>C:\wamp\www\rss\core\inc\rssnews.inc.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />`

Comment: If you're getting that error, you didn't put the `selectURL()` function into the argument list of `getFeed()`.

Comment: That error would happen if you wrote `getFeed()` instead of `getFeed(selectURL())`

Comment: Here is all the code:

`function selectURL () {
if(isset($_POST['Option']))
{
 $uid;
    $uid = $_POST['Option'];
 
 

}
return $uid;
}

if(isset($_GET['function']) && $_GET['function'] !='getFeed(selectURL())'){
 
    $result = $_GET['function']();
    echo json_encode($result);
 header("Content-type:application/json");
}`

Comment: `$_GET['function']` just contains `getFeed`, not `getFeed(selectURL())`.

Comment: It should be `$result = getFeed(selectURL());`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this is, though. You're just echoing back the parameter that was sent with AJAX. Why do you need to call a PHP script to do that?

Comment: Are these supposed to be two separate calls, one to select the URL and another to get what was selected? Then you should be saving the URL in a session variable, and returning that in `getFeed()`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I want

Comment: You should clarify this in the question.

Comment: Thank you brother, I just want to select the URL, once I get it, I use it on the function getFeed() to fetch RSS feed that's all